# How to get all parents for a given child node?

Tags: c#, linq

```
<siteNode controller="a" action="b" title="">
  <siteNode controller="aa" action="bb" title="" />
  <siteNode controller="cc" action="dd" title="">
    <siteNode controller="eee" action="fff" title="" />
    <siteNode controller="eee1" action="fff1" title="" />
  </siteNode>
</siteNode>
```

How can I get parents of a child node using LINQ?

For instance, if I gave the `controller="eee"` element, I would get back:

```
<siteNode controller="a" action="b" title="">
  <siteNode controller="aa" action="bb" title="" />
  <siteNode controller="cc" action="dd" title="">
```

I need to get all parent and grand parent nodes from the above sample.

Comment: Assuming that's XML, controller `aa` is _not_ a parent of controller `eee`.

Comment: @JeffMercado good point. I didn't even notice that. Do you mean you want the elements who fall *before* the given one, as compared to the ones who are its parents?

Comment: Sorry i need the output like this  <siteNode controller="a" action="b" title="">
    <siteNode controller="cc" action="dd" title=""> means that i need all parent nodes...

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> GetParents(XElement element)
{
    XElement cParent = element.Parent;
    while (cParent != null)
    {
        yield return cParent;
        cParent = cParent.Parent;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As Jeff pointed out in a comment, your example actually did have a closing tag on one of your "parent" rows, and thus should not have actually been included. If you actually meant "elements that fall before the given record, " as compared to its *parents*, you can use [`XNode.NodesBeforeSelf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.linq.xnode.nodesbeforeself(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: i need only parent nodes not all the nodes before to that node..can pls tell me to do that?

Comment: @user3331492 That's what my code block does. Did you try it?